# How to get the length of a int array(method paramater) inside a method?

Tags: c++, arrays, parameters, integer

My code is quite simple:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int test(int b[]){
    cout<<sizeof(b)<<endl;
    return 1;

}
int main(){
    int a[] ={1,2,3};
    cout<<sizeof(a)<<endl;
    test(a);
    system("pause");
}
```

output of this code is:

```
12
4
```

which means that when a[] is transfered as a parameter to function test(),is has been deteriorated as a int *, so the output of size(b) is 4 ,instead of 12.So ,my question is , how can I get the actual length of b[] inside function test() ?

Comment: hi, IIRC you cannot because the function parameter is a pointer. if you really need this feature you could use `std::array` or `std::vector`

Answer (score 6):

You could do this with a function template:

```
#include <cstddef> // for std::size_t

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t size(T (&)[N])
{ 
  return N;
}
```

then

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a[] ={1,2,3};
    std::cout << size(a) << std::endl;
}
```

Note that in C and C++, `int test(int b[])` is another way of saying `int test(int* b)`, so there is no array size information inside of the `test` function. Furthermore, you could use standard library container types which know their size, such as [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: Thank you .Your template solution is quite excellent.Thank you.